# Subquery with `WHERE` on function calls with outer query grouped by the function calls gives "subquery uses ungrouped column from outer query"

Tags: postgresql

Consider this situation where `age_group(.)` is a function that returns an age bracket for an age (0-17: 'minor', 18-64: 'adult' etc.)

```
SELECT
    date_of_data,
    age_group(age),
    count(1),
    (SELECT avg(salary)
     FROM tbl2
     WHERE age_group(tbl2.age) = age_group(tbl1.age)
     AND tbl2.date_of_file = tbl1.date_of_file
     AND type = 'junior') AS average_salary_as_junior,
    (SELECT avg(salary)
     FROM tbl2
     WHERE age_group(tbl2.age) = age_group(tbl1.age)
     AND tbl2.date_of_file = tbl1.date_of_file
     AND type = 'senior') AS average_salary_as_senior,
    (SELECT avg(salary)
     FROM tbl2
     WHERE age_group(tbl2.age) = age_group(tbl1.age)
     AND tbl2.date_of_file = tbl1.date_of_file
     AND type = 'principal') AS average_salary_as_principal,
     -- 15 more types to go
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY
    date_of_data, age_group(age);
```

This will not work unless the outer query is grouped by `age` in contrast to `age_group(age)`, because the subquery uses `age` as an argument to a function, despite being the same function:
`subquery uses ungrouped column "tbl1.age" from outer query`..

If I group by `age` instead of `age_group(age)`, there will be redundant identical records in the output.

Conditional aggregation might be a solution, and so is using `DISTINCT` on the whole output, albeit inefficient. Not sure if there are more techniques to achieve the same, but I am wondering whether there's a way to make Postgres realise that the same function call exists in the `GROUP BY` clause, and permit such a query to execute.

Comment: You can use subquery "select date_of_data, age_group, count(1) from (select date_of_data, age_group(age) as age_group, ....) group by date_of_data, age_group"

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, so you're suggesting materialising the function returns either in a subquery or perhaps in a CTE. I had the idea of storing the returns in a column as I have millions of records and 105 columns, but that might entail maintenance

Comment: @RDT, I might be wrong, but subquery without CTE doesn't affect materialize the resultset. Subquery is only way to workaround the SQL restrictions.

Comment: You're right, I used the term "materialise" rather carelessly. I meant to compute the returns beforehand, not storing them somewhere.